# Is it possible to have a shared global variable for inter-process communication?

Tags: c, linux

I need to solve a concurrency assignment for my operating systems class. I don't want the solution here, but I am lacking one part.

We should write a process that writes to file, reads from it and then deltetes it. This process we should run two times in two different shells. No fork here for simplicity. Process A should write, Process B then read and then Process should delete the file. Afterwards they switch roles.

I understand that you can achieve atomicity easily by locking. With while loops around the read-, and write sections etc. you can also get further control. But when I run process A and then process B, process B will spin before the write seciton until it achieves the lock and not got into reading when process A releases the lock. So my best guess is to have a read and a write lock. This information must be shared somehow between the processes. The only way I can think of is some global variable, but since both processes hold copies of the variables, I think this is not possible. Another way would be to have a read lock file and a write lock file, but that seems overly complicated to me.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use shared memory.

Comment: There are several ways to do inter-process communication. Some search terms are: Shared Memory, Pipes and Sockets.

Comment: I think we need to use shared memory. So would a pointer point to the same memory section, when I start both processes?

Comment: No, you have to ask the OS for a bit of shared memory. You would also have to ensure that the memory isn't being accessed by two tasks at the same time (e.g using some form of locking). Using a semaphore would make more sense.

Comment: Well, we are not allowed to use semaphores. We need to achieve this with file locks only

Answer (score 2):

You can use file as a lock. Two processes try to create a file with a previously agreed upon name using the O_EXCL flag. Only one will succeed. The one that succeeds gets the access to the resource. So in this case process A should try to create a file with name say, *foo*, with O_EXCL flag and, if successful, it should go ahead and write to file the information. After its work is complete, Process A should unlink *foo*. Process B should try to create file *foo* with O_EXCL flag, and if successful, try to read the file created by Process A. After its attempt is over, Process B should unlink the file *foo*. That way only one process will be accessing the file at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem (with files and alternating roles in the creation/deletion of files) seems to be a candidate to use the `O_EXCL` flag on opening/creating the file.  This flag makes the `open(2)` system call to succeed in creating a file **only** if the file doesn't exist, so it makes the file to appear as a semaphore itself.  Each process can liberate the lock (A or B) but the one that does, just liberates the lock and makes the role of *owning* again accessible.

You will see that both processes try to use one of the roles, but if they both try to use the *owner* role, one of them will succeed, and the other will fail.

Just enable a `SIGINT` signal handler on the *owning* process, to allow it to delete the file in case it gets signalled, or you will leave the file and after that no process will be able to assume the *owning* role (at least you will need to delete it manually).

This was the first form of locking feature in unix, long before semaphores, shared memory or other ways to block processes existed.  It is based on the atomicity of system calls (you cannot execute two system calls on the same file simultaneously)

Answer (score 1):

You can use semaphores to ensure the writer and deleter wait for the previous process to finish its job. (Use `man sem_init` for details)

When running multiple processes with semaphores, it should be created using shared mem (`man shm_open` for more details).

You will need as many semaphores as the number of pipelines in this process.

Comment: We are not allowed to use semaphores